# jsonpickle adds leading underscore to python object properties

Tags: python, jsonpickle

I am using jsonpickle to turn a nested python object into json. Python class:

```
class Cvideo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._url = None

    @property
    def url(self):
        return self._url

    @url.setter
    def url(self, value):
        self._url = value
```

Module for serialization:

```
def create_jason_request(self, vid1: Cvideo):
    vid1 = Cvideo()
    vid1.url = entry['uploader_url'] # will get a leading underscore
    vid1.notdefinedproperty = "test" # wont get a leading underscore in json

    return jsonpickle.encode(vid, unpicklable=False)
```

Unfortunately the created json depicts _url instead of url. How to avoid leading underscore creation in json when using pythin properties? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is entirely normal behaviour. Your instance *state* is stored, not the outside API. Properties are not part of the state, they are still methods and thus are part of the API.

If you must have `url` stored in the JSON result, then use the [`__getstate__` method](https://jsonpickle.github.io/api.html#customizing-json-output) to return a dictionary that better reflects your state. You'll have to create a matching `__setstate__` method:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    return {'url': self._url}

def __setstate__(self, state):
    self._url = state.get('url')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This enables me to steer the JSON result creation. One slight remark: I call the properties in __getstate__(self), for instance return {'url' self.url} because the properties encapsulate the logic to provide the appropriate value. Any design consideration with that?

Comment: @wuz: that's fine, just take into account that that is the value you'll get back to `__setstate__`.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Do you also know how to serialize a date property. Unfortunately, modifiy __getstate__ as fllows with strptime does not result in a json date mapping:- 'upload_date': datetime.datetime.strptime(self.upload_date, "%Y%m%d"),

Comment: @wuz: what is a JSON date mapping? JSON has no concept of dates.  Does [jsonpickle datetime to readable json format](//stackoverflow.com/q/19414672) help?

Comment: thanks for the hint. In order to make the serialized json to enable elasticsearch automated date mapping, the date has to match an exact format (e.g. yyyy-mm-dd without hh-mm-ss), all solved.